# Reference entity from different Context

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

Lets take a Product as an example. A Product can belong to a particular Group, so it has a reference property of type Group. Currently as it is coded each repository has its own context, so ProductViewModel receives in constructor IProductRepository and IGroupRepository, which have different ObjectContexts.

Question: if I assign Group entity to a particular Product, will Context from ProductRepository treat this assigned Group entity as new entity, since it didn't have any prior knowledge about it, and will try to add it to the database? If yes, how to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I assign Group entity to a particular Product, will Context from
>   ProductRepository treat this assigned Group entity as new entity,
>   since it didn't have any prior knowledge about it, and will try to add
>   it to the database?

Yes if you are using POCOs without lazy loading and dynamic change tracking (= non proxied entities). If you are using `EntityObject` based entities or proxied POCOs you will get exception.

> If yes, how to handle this scenario?

By using one context shared between both repositories.